# How crop image when comes out from parents div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, html

I have some problem
I try to write a image editor plugin, in this code I have 2 divs as you can see 
[image: image1]

this child div can drag and re size very well,after user re size it and click on upload bottom ,the information about child div place and exact size send to server perfectly.

but when child div drag and come out of parent div it dosent crop the extra part of image which come out of parent div.
[image: image2]

This is my html code

```
<div id="output">
   <div class="wifix" width="100%">
      <div class="dadycool">
         <div class="child" align="center"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**css codes**

```
div.wifix {
   height: 300px;
   width: 600px;
}
div.dadycool {
   width: 250px;
   height: 300px;
   overflow: hidden;
   outline: 1px dashed red;
   margin-top: 50px;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 100;
}
div.child {
   height: 400px;
   width: 500px;
   background: coral;
   left: -100px;
   right: 0;
   top: -50px;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `containment` in your code,

This will restrict your child element to move out of the parent element.

Eg:

```
   $( ".child" ).draggable({ containment: ".dadycool" });
```

See datails [here](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)